# Dictionary to guarantee order and getting by index

Tags: vb.net

I want future dictionary which would store values in the way `<key><value>`;
to guarantee order means every new item added to a list to be inserted as next one at the end. I read about that Dictionary is not good choice therefore I took a look at OrderedDictionary. Besides, I want to also have the possibility to get items by index (not key).

> My main question is whether did I choose OrderedList as the one I
>   should pick?

Nevertheless, I am struggling with getting items by index. Look below to understand the problem:

```
Dim _finalList As New OrderedDictionary

_finalList.Add("John", "Miles")
_finalList.Add("Jessica", "Brown")
```

Now neither one of the below which I tried works:

```
_finalList.Cast.ElementAt(0))
_finalList.Cast.ElementAt(0).Key.ToString())

_finalList.Cast(Of DictionaryEntry).ElementAt(0))
_finalList.Cast(Of DictionaryEntry).ElementAt(0).Key.ToString())
```

Error I get is like:

```
no public Cast member for the Ordered Dictionary type.
```

Comment: "John" as a key seems useless since keys must be unique; for any size collection at all you will have collisions. You also cant make up usage and syntax at your whimsy.  For instance there is no need to `Cast` since there is only one thing a `OrderedDictionary` can hold.  `miles = _finalList(0)` will get you the first value, `John = _finalList.Keys(0)` will get you the key.  This seems like an XY problem though.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a class for the items, and then have a List(Of YourClass) to store the data in. Can you explain why you need something like a dictionary please?

Comment: I mean it dont needt to be OrderedDictionary. I wrote what i need is to store values ina way of <T1, T2> in this case both T are strings. And to be able to get specific item's first and second value. Morover to keep sort - every new goes at the end. I am open to see any propositions as answer.

Comment: @Arie - Do you expect to remove elements from your dictionary? How should the indexing work if you do that?

Comment: does the order matter all the time...or when you do some type of processing...in that case...you can always convert the keys to an array...sort them before you loop through the keys

Comment: @Enigmativity yes i want to remove. If that would be the case i want elements to move for instance: item1(index0), item2(index1), item3(index2) when removing item2 i want this: item1(index0), item3(INDEX1)

Comment: @Plutonix when trying to use _finalist.Keys(0) i get an exception: System.MissingMemberException: 'The overload detection has failed because none of the available "Keys" elements accept this number of arguments.'   Nevertheless _finalist(0) - this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you finish this implementation:

```
Public Class MyKeyedCollection(Of K, V)
    Implements IDictionary(Of K, V)

    Private lookup = New Dictionary(Of K, V)
    Private items = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of K, V))

    Default Public Property Item(index As Integer) As V
        Get
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Get
        Set(value As V)
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Set
    End Property

    Default Public Property Item(key As K) As V Implements IDictionary(Of K, V).Item
        Get
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Get
        Set(value As V)
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Keys As ICollection(Of K) Implements IDictionary(Of K, V).Keys
        Get
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Values As ICollection(Of V) Implements IDictionary(Of K, V).Values
        Get
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of K, V)).Count
        Get
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReadOnly As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of K, V)).IsReadOnly
        Get
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Add(key As K, value As V) Implements IDictionary(Of K, V).Add
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(item As KeyValuePair(Of K, V)) Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of K, V)).Add
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Clear() Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of K, V)).Clear
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Sub CopyTo(array() As KeyValuePair(Of K, V), arrayIndex As Integer) Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of K, V)).CopyTo
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Sub

    Public Function ContainsKey(key As K) As Boolean Implements IDictionary(Of K, V).ContainsKey
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function

    Public Function Remove(key As K) As Boolean Implements IDictionary(Of K, V).Remove
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function

    Public Function Remove(item As KeyValuePair(Of K, V)) As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of K, V)).Remove
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function

    Public Function TryGetValue(key As K, ByRef value As V) As Boolean Implements IDictionary(Of K, V).TryGetValue
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function

    Public Function Contains(item As KeyValuePair(Of K, V)) As Boolean Implements ICollection(Of KeyValuePair(Of K, V)).Contains
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of KeyValuePair(Of K, V)) Implements IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of K, V)).GetEnumerator
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function

    Private Function IEnumerable_GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function

End Class
```

You just need to maintain the integrity of `lookup` and `items` under each of the operations.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. Could you explain me why not to use already some existing net lists? Second question why create own class and why implementing IDictionary there are so many methods to be written - could you explain why this way me to understand?